# Match two multidimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional array and i want to create a third multidimensional array:

```
var reports = [
    [48.98,153.48],
    [12.3,-61.64]
    ];

var vulc = [
    ["ciccio",48.98,153.48],
    ["cicci",12.3,-61.64],
    ["intruso",59.9,99.9]
    ];
```

And i want to create a new multidimensional array

```
var nuovarray= [];  


for (i=0; i<= reports.length; i++) {

   var attivi= reports[i];
   var attlat= attivi[0];
   var attlng= attivi[1];

    for (s=0;  s<=vulc.length; s++){
     var vulca= vulc[s];
     var vulcanam= vulca[0];
     var vulcalat= vulca[1];
     var vulcalng= vulca[2];

        if ((vulcalat==attlat) && (vulcalng==attlng){
            var stato= "A";
            nuovarray.push([vulcanam,vulcalat,vulcalng,stato]);     
        } 
        else{
            var stato= "N";
            nuovaarray.push([vulcanam,vulcalat,vulcalng,stato]);     
        }    

    }

}
```

i would like to have

```
var nuovarray= [
    ["ciccio",48.98,153.48,"N"],
    ["cicci",12.3,-61.64,"N"],
    ["intruso",59.9,99.9,"A"]
    ];
```

But i don't know if this code is good :/

Comment: If your code works and you only want to know if/how it's good, then your question is on-topic to [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Here it's off-topic/

Comment: in the for loop, use < not <= (array of length N has indexes 0 ... N-1) ... and swap the outer loop with the inner loop, and only push with value 'N' before the end of the outer loop if the inner loop hasn't pushed with value 'A'

Comment: @JaromandaX yes the **<=** it was a stupid error, but why i must swap loops ?

Comment: it makes sense to swap loops ... based on your sample output, you want one output per `vulc`, not one output per `reports` - so, you process each `vulc` to see if a `report` matches, not the other way around

Comment: I think you need a different approach, do you really need a 3 dimesions array or you just need to keep the state in the 2 dimesions arrary?

Comment: 2 dimensions array, but new array with a new element ("N" or "A")

Comment: Why are the members of `vulc` arrays and not objects ? It looks like semantics are inferred from position...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, in the for loop, use < not <= (array of length N has indexes 0 ... N-1) ... and swap the outer loop with the inner loop, and only push with value 'N' before the end of the outer loop if the inner loop hasn't pushed with value 'A'

```js
var reports = [
    [48.98,153.48],
    [12.3,-61.64]
];

var vulc = [
    ["ciccio",48.98,153.48],
    ["cicci",12.3,-61.64],
    ["intruso",59.9,99.9]
];

var nuovarray= [];  

for(var s = 0; s < vulc.length; s++) {
    var vulca = vulc[s];
    var stato= "A"; // default, no match
    var vulcanam= vulca[0];
    var vulcalat= vulca[1];
    var vulcalng= vulca[2];

    for(var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
        var attivi = reports[i];
        var attlat= attivi[0];
        var attlng= attivi[1];
    
        if ((vulcalat==attlat) && (vulcalng==attlng)) {
            stato = "N";
            break; // we've found a match, so set stato = N and stop looping
        }
    }
    nuovarray.push([vulcanam,vulcalat,vulcalng,stato]);     
}


document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = (nuovarray).toSource();
```

```html
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: the problem is that i would like an example using for loop and not methods that i don't know :/ thanks

Comment: i'm sure that your code is good and works, but i don't understand it :((

Comment: fair enough - let me rewrite it

Comment: you are too kind and patient ! :)

Comment: works very good! is a few months that I do not program in Javascript and I had forgotten the use of "break"! thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code will not work the way it is written. At least, it will not give you the expected output. You are iterating through the vulc array inside the loop which iterates through reports. And you are pushing to the nuovarray inside the inner loop. So I would expect 6 elements in nuovarray, not the 3 elements you are expecting. 
Did you try running it? That's the easiest way to prove incorrectness.

Comment: This should be a comment, not answer

Comment: yes and doesn't works... is difficult for me match two multidimensional array, so i hope in help :(

Comment: i'm sure that your code is good and works, but i don't understand it :((

Answer (score 0):

```
var reports = [
    [48.98,153.48],
    [12.3,-61.64]
];

var vulc = [
    ["ciccio",48.98,153.48],
    ["cicci",12.3,-61.64],
    ["intruso",59.9,99.9]
];

var nuovarray = [];

vulc.forEach(function(item, indx){

    var bN = 'undefined' !== typeof reports[indx];
    bN = bN && item[1] == reports[indx][0] && item[2] == reports[indx][1];

    item.push(bN ? 'N' : 'A'); 

    nuovarray.push(item);

});

console.log(nuovarray);
```

Comment: why `.map` and not `.forEach` - your not actually 'map'ping anything?

Comment: `.map` returns a copy of the array. `.forEach` doesn't

Answer (score 0):

The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.
[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.
[Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.
[Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var reports = [
  [48.98,153.48],
  [12.3,-61.64]
];

var vulc = [
  ["ciccio",48.98,153.48],
  ["cicci",12.3,-61.64],
  ["intruso",59.9,99.9]
];

console.log(vulc.map(function (item, index) {
  item.push(reports.some(function (report) {
    return report[0] == item[1] && report[1] == item[2];
  })?"N":"A");

  return item;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code maps the given `vulc` to `nuovarray` and add the wanted flag to it. The flag is selected by a search over `reports` and if found, an `'N'` is applied, otherwise an `'A'` is applied.

```js
var reports = [
      [48.98, 153.48],
      [12.3, -61.64]
    ],
    vulc = [
      ["ciccio", 48.98, 153.48],
      ["cicci", 12.3, -61.64],
      ["intruso", 59.9, 99.9]
    ],
    nuovarray = vulc.map(function (a) {
        a.push(reports.some(function (b) {
            return a[1] === b[0] && a[2] === b[1];
        }) ? 'N' : 'A')
        return a;
    });
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(nuovarray, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance matters, you should use something better than O(n^2):

```
var existingPoints = {};
reports.forEach(function (row) {
    existingPoints[row.join()] = true;
});

var nuovarray = vulc.map(function (row) {
    var point = row.slice(1, 3).join();
    var flag = existingPoints[point] ? 'A' : 'N';
    return row.concat([flag]);
});
```